# In Angular storing the server response for n number of data in local storage is a good way to avoid page refresh ? Any other Better way

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am created an Eshopping  Mvc application with webapi and angularjs:

Read and answer:

Application heirarchy for 1 module:
**Login => Home=> retailer => retailerlist => product => product list**

Application working fine in this scenario:
when inside the Dom , event fires means carry over the data and get into child controller  variable.

Home controller event fires ,

var HomeController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $stateParams, $state,  LogService,HomeService)

LogService.Login("username", encodeURIComponent("password"))
                          .then(function (response) {

```
  var SessionData = response.SessionObj;

  var DefaultModelObj = { SessionObj: SessionData,  add dynamic property};

 HomeService.pageLoad(DefaultModelObj)
                         .then(function (response) {
                       $rootScope.SessionObj = response.SessionObj

});

}
```

Service might be like this

```
var LogService = function ($http, $q) {
        this.Login = function (userName, passWord) {
            var result = $q.defer();

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: server url 
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
           .success(function (response) {
                result.resolve(response);
           })
           .error(function (response) {
               result.reject(response);          
           });

            return result.promise;
        }
    }
```

like this home  service , other services.

when accesing the response from page event fires get the value and working fine.

**`ui-sref="home.retailer" ng-click="onSelection(dataItem)"`**

In state url , it goes and working fine because of getting the  data in  dataItem  and access the values in particular controller .

**Note : Everything inside the DOM.**

Not working:
consider i am taking one module,
**At the point of time , i am in retailer list page , its child of login => home => retailer => retailerlist.**

i have do the page refresh or F5,

```
var RetailerListController = function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, logService, homeService, retailerService, retailerlistservice)


**`var SessionData = $rootScope.CT1SessionObj; // getting  undefined happen in browser refresh loss the data.`**
```

Note: above i have said , Evnt fires takes the values in page navigation working fine.

Steps: for avoiding those i have handle below steps:

In controller Service response depends on

1)call the login service and getting the response some added code from the reponse.

2)pass to Home service and getting the response and some alter and pass to retailer.

3)getting the home response and pass to retailer .

4) getting the  retailer response and pass to retailer list .

**Note: this working fine .**

```
  LogService.Login("username", encodeURIComponent("password"))
                .then(function (response) {

                  var SessionData = response.SessionObj;
                  var DefaultModelObj = { SessionObj: SessionData, do something};


                    // another service call
                  HomeService.pageLoad(DefaultModelObj)
                          .then(function (response) {
                             $rootScope.SessionObj = response.SessionObj;

                             var getresponse= { SessionObj: SessionData, //do some thing added };


              // another service call
                     retailerService.pageLoad( getresponse)
                        .then(function (response) {
                                              var x = response.SessionObj;

                                                    // another  service call

                                                  retailerListService.pageLoad(x)
                                                    .then(function (response) {
                                    $rootScope.SessionObj = response.SessionObj;

                          }, function (response) {
                      alert(response.Message)
                  });

});
});
```

Note:

My Question is 
In every child controller , **i have to pass the parent controller response ?
its a better way?** or else i have to store the response of each object in local storage to refresh the page issue  because **of lossing values.**

Single object service call contains minimum 100 values:

consider Home service response have 100 values , like that retailer service response and store to local storage is means its a good way and  else it will lead to any attack?

Note : IS there any better way:

Comment: Try to consolidate this into a more concise problem statement. Hard to read all this and assimilate what exactly your issue is. Also please format code with proper indent for readability

Comment: simple : i am not given the entire code, i have post the flow of the code just read the heirachy? the problem is not getting a value in rootscope when page refresh happens , for avoiding those i have found some solution , i dont know its a correct way or not, in rootscope i am setting a response from service call, getting undefined,  each service response have 100 property values and every thing i have stored in local storage is good way or i have call the parent heirachy in evry child controller.

Comment: localStorage might help. If using ui-router can set up a parent state and a resolve on that state. Then all child states have access to that resolve. No need to make same request in all children that way

Comment: little bit confusing, can you give one resolve sample statement here ?

Comment: Lots of tutorials on web... I quickly did google search and this seems like good example https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/advanced-routing-and-resolves-a2fcbf874a1c#.2lzn2dtr7

Comment: Thanks man .. good one